# Custom Email Composer View for Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to provide email sending functionality in my iPad app. I want to have the same/similar view that the mail app uses for sending emails but the functionality of the send button will be different. Do I need to create this view from scratch or is there a shortcut?

Comment: From scratch (or something from github maybe), and using your own mail server.

Comment: Okay so the mail server is not an issue. I have that ready, just need to make a POST call. But I don't really know how to make this VC from scratch. I don't know what UI components are used for the To , CC BCC, Subject and message fields

Answer (score 1):

Well, you **cant** directly integrate a custom view to the native iOS email controller because of API limits in iOS. But you **can** customize the appearance of the said button using `UIAppearence`. See Apple's Developer refrence: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Here's a nice tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6 . It's for iOS 6 but `UIApperance` still works the same way in iOS 7.

If `UIAppearence` doesn't work out, then your only other option is to integrate SDK's/API's for the popular email services. Use this ***only*** if you **know** what kind of email your user is using as you cant possibly plan for every kind of email. Here are a few links for the most popular email services:

- Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/
- Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/
- Excahnge: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn448484